# Let $p: E \to B$ be a covering map. If $B$ is a completely regular space then prove that (edited) $E$ is completely regular space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $p: E \to B$ be a covering map. If $B$ is a completely regular space then prove that $E$ is completely regular space. I am getting no clue how to construct the function $f$.

The readers may check the same problem here [Is a covering space of a completely regular space also completely regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651745/is-a-covering-space-of-a-completely-regular-space-also-completely-regular)

No answer is there also.

Comment: This is a tautology: if $B$ is a completely regular space then $B$ is a completely regular space.

Comment: There's a typo, presumably. It should be: $B$ completely regular implies $E$ completely regular.

Comment: Here is a complete answer by David White  on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/80642/450).

Comment: Two Notes on the Answer from [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/80642/450):  the last sentence follows from the pasting lemma, and Munkres' hint is only used to prove that one point sets are closed in E.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use exactly a pullback $f$ (in fact you can't). You actually have a good deal of flexibility in constructing functions. Try to visualize the function you'd want, then prove that you can make a function like that.

---

Here's a hint to get you going: Given $x \in E$ and $V \subset E$ closed not meeting $x$, find an open neighborhood $N$ of $x$ small enough to both miss $V$ and satisfy the covering condition, by which I mean p(N) satisfies the covering condition (why can you do this?).

Then construct a function on $B$ which is $0$ at $p(x)$ and is $1$ on $B - p(N)$.

You'll want some nested neighborhoods in what follows, so now take $N$ smaller, say by intersecting with the set where p composed with this function is less than 1/2, and then construct this type of function again.

Now modify the pullback of the function near other lifts of p(N) to get you what you want and prove your modification is still continuous.

Comment: Dear aes, I don't think this works at all. If you disagree, please post a complete solution instead of alluding to undefined modifications (every function is a modification of any other function, after all ). And by the way, it doesn't make sense to say that $N$ satisfies the covering condition.

Comment: This is a homework problem, so I'd prefer not to give a complete solution. What step are you stuck on?

Comment: I've cleaned it up a bit and clarified the minor circumlocution regarding N satisfying the covering condition. But really, if the purpose of this site is to post polished complete solutions to students' problem set problems, I'll take my business elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think this has any chance to work because all connected components of $p^{-1}(p(N)) $ except $N$ might be included in $V$ and then the lift $f\circ p$ of your function $f$ downstairs will take the value $0$ at all points $ y\in p^{-1}(p(x))$ of the fiber  of $p(x)$ with  $y\neq x$. How are you going to modify $f\circ p$ in order to obtain a function taking the value $1$ at all those $y$'s, given that you don't know whether  $V$ is completely regular?

Comment: Make the modification identically 1 on other lifts.

Comment: Such a modification will obviously not be continuous. Anyway,  this site is not for long dialogues trying  to extract some precise answer from users: unless you furnish what mathematicians agree is a proof, I consider you haven't answered the question and will no longer comment on your "hints".

Comment: This is an exercise in Munkres, an undergraduate textbook, not some research problem we are discussing. The modification is continuous because it is already identically 1 between some nested neighborhoods at the other lifts. I am not posting here to gain acclaim for having proved this exercise from Munkres.