# Complete regularity for a covering map.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How do I show that if $p:E\to B$ is a covering map, then if $B$ is completely regular then also $E$ is completely regular?

Thanks.
If I take $x\in E$ and a closed set $x\notin F \subset E$; then I want to show that there exists a continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$ s.t $f(x)=1 , f(F)=\{ 0\}$.

Let's look at $p(x)=y$ , it has an open nbhd, $U_b$ which is evenly covered by $p$ in $B$, i.e $p^{-1}(U_b) = \bigsqcup_{\alpha} V_\alpha$.
$E\setminus F$ is an open nbdh of $x$, so $p(E\setminus F)$ is an open nbhd of $y$, if we take $B\setminus p(E\setminus F)$ as a closed set that doesn't contain $y$, then by complete regularity of $B$, we have a continuous function $g: B \to [0,1]$ s.t $g(y) = 1 , g(B\setminus p(E\setminus F)) = \{ 0\}$.
$f(x)= g\circ p (x) =1 , g\circ p (F) = \{ 0\}$.

Is this right or totally wrong, can you please help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: You do not use the "evenly coveredness" (i.e. $U_b$ which would be better named $U_y$). You do use $p$ is open (which is correct). Also $p[E \setminus F]$ could equal $B$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/651745/4280